# Minecraft skyblock farming

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I'm playing on a pic server called mc.origins.com and I'm playing skyblock. I built a huge cactus farm and I'm wondering why it won't grow overnight. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stay online near it for the farm to work. Otherwise it won't grow anything. I would suggest building an afk pool, here's a tutorial on how to build one. [afk pool tutorial](https://youtu.be/dr9shueFN5w)

Comment: @Jacobmiller you are very welcome